# Trying to understand why 2 times the sum of consecutive integers from 0 to n is equal to n times n+1

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, integers

I am sorry if this question ends up being a duplicate, as I am having a bit of a challenge explaining it to myself well enough to know how to query it.

There is a Facebook meme that has been circulating for a while that has a list that shows:

> 2 = 6
>
> 3 = 12
>
> 4 = 20

etc.

Once you get beyond the notation, you can see that there are at least two ways to arrive at the value on the right hand side of the equality.

You can get it by multiplying $n(n+1)$, for example $n = 3$ yields $(3)(4) = 12$, or you can arrive at it by considering $2\sum_{i=1}^n i$. For example the product of 2 and $\sum_{i=3}^n i$ is 12.

This implies that

$$2\sum_{i=0}^n i = (n_i)(n_{i+1});\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$$

This can be generalized to say

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{(n_i)(n_{i+1})}{2};\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$$

And here is where I don't know how to proceed in thinking about this.

I don't see the relationship between the sum of consecutive integers to n being one half the product of n times n+1.

Actually I don't think I understand what question I should be asking so if anyone can clarify what is going on I would appreciate it. I can see the pattern, but I would like to understand why the pattern holds the way that it does.

Comment: There are some great "proofs without words" for this (as well as standard proofs by induction or other means).  Here may be a useful reference:  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Proofs_without_words

Answer (score 2):

Lore has it that Gauss discovered a particularly neat way of deriving this result as a child:

Consider $S=1+2+3+\dots+n$. By commutativity, we also have $S=n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+1$. So it follows $$S=1+2+3+\dots+n\\S=n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+1\\2S=(1+n)+(2+(n-1))+(3+(n-2))+\dots+(n+1)$$... by adding terms in pairs. Notice each of these pairs sums to $k+(n-k+1)=n+1$, so we have: $$2S=\underbrace{(n+1)+\dots+(n+1)}_{n\text{ copies}}\\2S=n(n+1)$$

Comment: There are actually many more proofs of this, for example, one could proceed by induction, or by some kind of "proof without words" as lulu suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a classic story about Gauss being asked by the teacher to compute the sum of 1 + 2 + 3 + ...100 as punishment, when he was in the third grade, and immediately come up with the answer of 5050.

Gauss' thinking was: 1+100 = 101, 2+99=101, and so on, and there are 50 such pairs.

This method can be applied to all A.P's.